# Python bs4 module

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, user-warning

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

'''
It's a web crawler working in ebay, collecting every single item data
'''

def ebay_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Apple-Laptops/111422/i.html?_pgn=' \
              + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)

        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'vip'}):
            href = 'http://www.ebay.co.uk' + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
    get_single_item_data(href)
    page += 1


def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('h1', {'id': "itemTitle"}):
        print(item_name.string)

ebay_spider(3)
```

> Blockquote And the error say that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbJ6y.jpg
>   I tried to fix it but it seems not to work, so any tips/answers how to fix it?
>
> EDIT: Sorry everyone for faulty title and tag, everything was fixed.

Comment: have you tried what it tells you? `soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser",markup_type=markup_type)`. And please post text version of the error, not an unreadable image.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `requests` module.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre sorry mate for bad pic, but you readed error right. But the problem is that I pasted that line into my code and error appears that says: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. For some weird reason I can't find what's wrong with it. And here is the previous error, what post was about:  http://pastebin.com/HNL1ENG0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to make a BeatifulSoup object in line, do instead this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
```

This:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
```

Note: your problem refers to bs4 module, not requests.

Comment: Excuse me sir, sorry for faulty title and tag(my bad) and thanks for answer but then I write this line it says : SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. imgur.com/a/8NBDi

Comment: If you musn't specify markup_type do this:soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser') instead this: soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser', markup_type=markup_ty‌​pe)  . And if my response was useful, mark it as useful.

Comment: I have changed my answer fit to your needs. I refer you to look: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ .

Comment: I tried to write the version than you edited and that is on crummy.com but it still says the same. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/8mrjy6Mc  and here is the error: http://pastebin.com/HrDLi6G6    Please help me if you could

Comment: Look to first function, you didn't change all of soup definitions, look at 14th line and do the same as you did with 25th line.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely unrelated to the requests module. AS Jean-Francois stated, do what it tells you and move along.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser",markup_type=markup_ty‌​pe)`

Comment: Excuse me sir, sorry for faulty title and tag(my bad) nd thanks for answer but then I write this line it says : SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier.   http://imgur.com/a/8NBDi